# MSSQL DDL Create with 3 values in employee status (0=working, 1=paid leave, 2=out)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning SQL DDL statement and I don't know what command/query to use with Employe status for this assignment. Please point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

> **Assignment:** Create table Employee with Employee level ranging from 1 to 7; Employee status with 0 = working, 1 = paid leave, 2 = out

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
EmpID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
EmpLevel TINYINT CHECK (1<=EmpLevel<=7)
EmpStatus
```

Comment: Use an EmployeeLevel table and add an FK constraint from EmpLevel to that table's primary key. That's the only thing that actually specifies what those values do.

Comment: You can also use a check constraint but the application will have to guess what those values are. The syntax is the same as a WHERE clause, eg `CHECK (EmpLevel Between 1 and 7)` or `CHECK (EmpLevel >=1 and EmpLevel <=7)`. This will stop working if you want to add more levels, or remove one level. There's no such problem if you use a lookup table for the levels

Comment: What about Employee status 0=working, 1=paid leave, 2=out. How do I represent that in the query?

Comment: You can't. Relations are represented by tables. The table `EmployeeLevel` represents the relation between the `ID` value and the `Status` name. When you create a Foreign Key *constraint* between Employee and EmployeeLevel you're saying that the column `EmpLevel` can only take values that are valid (exists) in the `EmployeeLevel` table

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    EmpID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    EmpLevel TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK (EmpLevel Between 1 and 7),
    EmpStatus int null)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was not clear about my question. How do I represent Employee status 0=working, 1=paid leave, 2 = out)

Comment: I already answered that in the very first comment - use an EmployeeLevel lookup table. Relations are represented by *tables* in relational databases, not foreign keys